# SQL Server : Insert get user agent

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to do an `insert` into a SQL Server table for auditing when logging in to an admin panel. I want to find out what device they are using. How would I do this?

This is what I have so far and it doesn't work it gives me an error that the statement has been terminated.

```
string sUA = Request.UserAgent;

using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.audit ([user], [login], [pass], [timestamp], [device]) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', @time, @device)", Connection = sqlCon })
    {
        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now);
        sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device", sUA);

        sqlCon.Open();

        {
           sqlCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

           sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide error message why statement is terminated?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.

The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Check you column's lengths - something you're trying to insert is **too long** for the column you're trying to insert it into! My guess would be the `[device]` column which gets the user agent string - how long is it defined in the database? How long is the user agent string you're trying to insert into it??

Comment: That means that the data you are inserting is bigger than the field. User Agent strings can get pretty long. It may be simplest to set the field to varchar(max). If that doesn't work you will need to look at the other fields and ensure they aren't set to something like varchar(1) by accident.  
Also, to figure out exactly what the browser is you can try the HttpBrowserCapabilities object which can make figuring it out much easier> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It works I gave it MAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

That means the data you tried to insert is too big for one or more of the column.

You have to increase the size of whichever column is too small (I have a suspicion it's your device column, but we can't tell unless we see your table structure, and your test data)

Comment: that is weird cause i gave it 100 characters. nvarchar(100)

Comment: @BillyBoel and what about timestamp column? what is type of it?

Comment: Actually it works i had to give the nvchar(MAX) for some reason it doesn't give me the correct user agent though.  It gave me this Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36

Comment: That looks like a correct user agent string for a recent Chrome. These things get pretty long and complicated.

Comment: So how do you know if its chrome or mozilla?

Comment: http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua, checking chrome's matches your string. Just as a design note, checking against User Strings is quite an annoying process, and can cause lots of issues... What are you trying to do?